# Having trouble with server.htmlDecode() returning a JSON string from Database with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, json, decode, html-encode

I have created a function which essentially enables me to output anything I need from my database in a similar method to Facebook's FQL querying method as a JSON text result.

I can also use the same function to get the output as a Dictionary, or List of(Dictionary) to use with VB functions for other purposes.

```
Public Shared Function getDataList(sql As String, output As String, useDb As String, labelName As String, fileName As String)
    Dim dataDetail
    '' This function will return the content of a query as either a key/value dictionary, or a key(key/value) result for formating 
    '' as JSON for JS handling or a Dictionary to use with server side codes

    If labelName <> "" Then
        dataDetail = New List(Of Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String))
    Else
        dataDetail = New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String))
    End If

    Dim connection As OdbcConnection = Common.getConnection(useDb)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim connect As OdbcCommand = Common.createCommand(sql, connection, useDb)

        Dim getData As New DataTable()
        getData.Load(connect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
        For Each row In getData.Rows
            Dim rowDetail As New Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
            For Each column In getData.Columns
                Dim theData = row(column)

                If IsDBNull(theData) Then
                    theData = ""
                End If
                If LCase(output) = "json" Then
                    theData = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(theData)
                End If

                    rowDetail.Add(column.ToString, theData)

            Next

        Next
        connection.Close()
    Catch theError As Exception
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(theError)
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try
    If output = "json" Then
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(dataDetail))
    ElseIf output = "dictionary" Then
        Return dataDetail
    End If
End Function
```

This works fine and I have found it very useful for getting data from my database in quick fashion.

The only problem I have is that when I get the output as a JSON file, I want anything which is stored in the database as Encoded HTML to be converted so it's shown nicely in the browser.

The line

```
theData = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(theData)
```

Is meant to do this, and does... kinda... but today this character:

```
&#39;
```

Isn't decoding.

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

Ah... that character is not supported!

I have created my own functions instead

```
Public Shared Function htmlDecode(str As String) As String
    Return Replace(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlDecode(str), "&#39;", "'")
End Function

Public Shared Function htmlEncode(str As String) As String
    Return Replace(HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(str), "&#39;", "'")
End Function
```

All working now!